# Executing code directly throws exception correctly but within a function doesn't

Tags: promise, async-await, graphql

I'm trying to throw exception in the async code. If I throw it directly like this, it works fine. Example:

```
  Query: {
    requisitions: async (parent, args, { req }, info) => {
      const user = await Auth.findOne({ _id: req.session.userId }).select('roles')
      if (!user.roles.some(role => ['driver', 'requestant'].includes(role))) {
        throw new ForbiddenError(ErrorCodes.UNAUTHENTICATED)
      }

      return true
    }
}
```

But if I make a helper function to handle this, it doesn't work. I need the helper function because this roles check is needed at many places in the app.

```
  Query: {
    requisitions: async (parent, args, { req }, info) => {
      hasRights(req, ['driver', 'requestant'])

      return true
    }
}

export const hasRights = async (req, allowedRoles) => {
    const user = await Auth.findOne({ _id: req.session.userId }).select('roles')
    if (!user.roles.some(role => allowedRoles.includes(role))) {
      throw new ForbiddenError(ErrorCodes.UNAUTHENTICATED)
    }
}
```

Note: the hasRights is exported from another file.

I have tried all combinations of try/catch blocks in both files but I just get the UnhandlePromiseRejectionWarning in the server console but the `requisitons` resolver continues in execution. I want it to stop if the exception is thrown. I have no idea why it only works one way and not the other, even though it is the same thing. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does every place you call `hasRights()` use a `.catch()` or chain to a promise chain that has a `.catch()`?  Does every place you call `requisitions()` do the same?  Or, if called from within an `async` function, is it surrounded by `try/catch`?   You aren't showing enough code to reproduce the issue as we need to see calling code too for a situation that causes the error.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm calling `hasRights()` only here at the moment. The first code snippet doesn't use any `try/catch` and it works (eslint even points out it is unnecessary to just re-throw the error in the `catch` block - `no-useless-catch` rule. That's why I'm so confused with the second solution because it is the same thing in essence. I tried to use `try/catch` blocks everywhere but it still didn't stop `requisitions` resolver in execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `hasRights(req, ['driver', 'requestant'])` can return a rejected promise, but you have no code to ever handle that.  As such, it's an unhandled rejection.

When the throw is inline, it's caught by the `async` `requsitions()` function which then returns a rejected promise so the caller of `requisitions()` has a chance to catch it.

You can make sure a rejected promise returned from `hasRights()` is handled the same way by adding `await` in front of the `hasRights()` call like this:

```
Query: {
  requisitions: async (parent, args, { req }, info) => {
    await hasRights(req, ['driver', 'requestant'])
    return true
  }
}
```

This will allow the `async` `requisitions()` function to automatically catch a rejection from `hasRights()` the same way your original inline `throw` did.

You will, of course, have to make sure you handle rejected promises properly in the callers of `requisitions()`.

---

It also occurs to me that you need to know that executing a `throw` inside an `async` function will be automatically caught by the `async` function and converted into a rejection of the promise that is returned by the `async` function.  This is a feature of `async` functions.

Comment: Got this, thank you!! The only thing I was missing was that `await` keyword in front of the `hasRights` call. Somehow, no `try/catch` block is needed.